# Join 2 separate tables with same field names into a brand new table

Tags: sql

I have looked everywhere and I cannot locate exactly what I am trying to figure out.

These are the two tables I have:

1st table: PET
Field Names: PET_ID (INT), PET_BREED (VARCHAR2(25)), PET_NAME (VARCHAR2(25)), PET_VALUE (NUMBER*8,2)), PET_DATE (DATE)

2nd table: PET2
Field Names: PET2_ID (INT), PET2_BREED (VARCHAR2(25)), PET2_NAME (VARCHAR2(25)), PET2_VALUE (NUMBER*8,2)), PET2_DATE (DATE)

I want to combine all records from PET and all records from PET2 into a new table named PET3 without creating any duplicate rows. The PET_ID numbers are not the same, but there are a few rows in PET2 where all the other fields match the records from PET table.

I have to use ORACLE EXPRESS 10g for this class assignment. Starting to feel like I'm beating my head against the wall. Not sure if I am trying to do something that can't be done or not.

Does the PET3 table have to be created first and then combine the information from the other two tables into it, or can it be done all at once?

Your help will be greatly greatly appreciated. I will keep hunting until I hear.
Thank you!
DCM

Answer (score 1):

SELECT INTO the new table from PET, then do the same for PET2 using NOT EXISTS. Read up on that and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I think I almost have it, but I am still missing something, because I am using the following and if I leave out the "INTO" then I get a view of the rows that I want to insert into PET3, but if I leave "INTO" in then I get an error ORA-00936 missing expression. Here is the statement I have entered. SELECT INTO PET_ID,PET_BREED,PET_NAME, PET_VALUE,PET_DATE
FROM PET2
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * 
FROM PET3
WHERE PET3.PET_NAME = PET2.PET_NAME);              Thank you!

Comment: you're not saying where you're inserting it to. SELECT (...) INTO MyResultTable FROM PET2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)

Comment: I greatly appreciate all your help. Still not working. Is it the syntax? Here is what I have tried and I am still getting error messages ORA-00905 missing keyword (PET3 is an existing table, is that ok?): SELECT PET_ID,PET_BREED,PET_NAME, PET_VALUE,PET_DATE INTO PET3 FROM PET2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PET3 WHERE PET3.PET_NAME = PET2.PET_NAME);

Comment: SELECT INTO creates a new table. The syntax you need is INSERT INTO PET3 (PET_ID,PET_BREED,PET_NAME, PET_VALUE,PET_DATE)  SELECT PET_ID,PET_BREED,PET_NAME, PET_VALUE,PET_DATE FROM PET2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PET3 WHERE PET3.PET_NAME = PET2.PET_NAME); –

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any db engine where I could test it right now, so please don't take my statement very serious but why not using something like this? is it what you are trying to do?

```
SELECT INTO new_table FROM (SELECT PET_ID, PET_BREED, PET_NAME, PET_VALUE, PET_DATE FROM PET UNION SELECT PET2_ID as PET_ID, PET2_BREED as PET_BREED, PET2_NAME as PET_NAME, PET2_VALUE as PET_VALUE, PET2_DATE as PET_DATE)
```

of course you have to run create table new_table with expected structure before that